# find commit by subject line from git

Tags: git

I know a commit with subject should be in git, but do not know which branch it belong to. how can I find the commit has specific subject?

Below command only run on current branch:

```
git log --oneline |grep subject
```

Answer (score 1):

[`:/^[^\n]*subject`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtlttextgtemegemHEADfixnastybugem) names the most recent commit with that in its subject reachable from any ref. `git branch --contains ':/^[^\n]*subject'` shows all the branches containing that commit. For script usage `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads --contains ':/^[^\n]*subject'` won't gratuitously add markup.

If you don't want to confine the search to just the subject line you can lose the `^[^\n]*` anchor.

Comment: git branch only list the branch name, right? I would like to find all commits contains subject

Comment: "all commits" is not "a commit", and commits can be reachable from any number of branches. Most old commits are reachable from all branch tips. Could you explain what you're planning on doing once you've got an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can grep the log directly with:
`git log --all --grep="subject"`

Comment: git log only list commits in current branch, right?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the --all flag.
I think that this should work:

`git log --all --grep="subject"`

Comment: then better edit your original answer so that readers do not need to read through all the comments